# Couldn't find learner 'classif.lightgbm'

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, random-forest, lightgbm

I'm trying to make an ensemble learning function, using lightGBM as the main learners and random forest as the meta learner. My target variable `CR` is binary, and I want to use this function on several data sets, some of them have predictive features that are only binary, and some have non-binary features. It recieves the data as a list, and it splits it.

At the very end, I just want the final best model out of the stacked models.

All of the packages I'm using have been loaded and updated. Yet, I'm facing a problem while using `lightgbm` that I wasn't able to solve:

```
Error in makeLearner("classif.lightgbm", predict.type = "prob", fix.factors.prediction = TRUE, : 
Couldn't find learner 'classif.lightgbm'
Did you mean one of these learners instead: classif.gbm classif.h2o.gbm classif.logreg
```

The `mlr::makeLearner` is not identifying `classif.lightgbm`, and I heven't found a way to overcome this problem. Have a look on my whole code:

```
ensemble_learner <- function(data, n_models = 10, cpus = 32) {
  
  train <- data[[1]]
  test <- data[[2]]
  
  lgbm_param_grid <- list(objective = "binary",
                          boosting_type = "gbdt",
                          learning_rate = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5),
                          num_leaves = c(3, 5, 10, 20),
                          max_depth = c(-1, 5, 10),
                          bagging_fraction = c(0.5, 0.8, 1),
                          feature_fraction = c(0.5, 0.8, 1),
                          alpha = c(0, 1, 3, 7),
                          lambda = c(0, 1, 3, 7),
                          gamma = c(0, 1, 3, 7))
  
  
  # define the base learner function for LightGBM 
  lgbm_learner <- makeLearner("classif.lightgbm",
                              predict.type = "prob",
                              fix.factors.prediction = TRUE,
                              verbose = FALSE,
                              par.vals = lgbm_param_grid,
                              tune.threshold = 0.9,
                              num.trees = 1000,
                              early.stopping.rounds = 50,
                              early.stopping.margin = 0.01,
                              nthread = cpus)
  
  # hyperparameters for Random Forest
  rf_params <- list(mtry = sqrt(ncol(train)),
                    importance = TRUE)
  
  parallelStartSocket(cpus = cpus)
  
  # metalearnr function for Random Forest
  rf_learner <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest",
                            predict.type = "prob",
                            fix.factors.prediction = TRUE,
                            verbose = FALSE,
                            params = rf_params)
  
  # stacked ensemble using logistic regression
  stack_learner <- makeStackedLearner(learners = list(lgbm_learner),
                                      meta.learner = rf_learner,
                                      method = "glm",
                                      predict.type = "prob",
                                      fix.factors.prediction = TRUE,
                                      verbose = FALSE)
  
  # set up the resampling strategy
  folds <- makeCrossValidationWrapper(stack_learner, iters = 10)
  
  # train the stacked ensemble on the training set
  stacked_model <- train(stack_learner,
                         task = makeClassifTask(data = train, target = "CR"),
                         resampling = folds,
                         verbose = FALSE,
                         control = list(allowParallel = TRUE,
                                        cpus = cpus))
  

  parallelStop()
  
  return(stacked_model)
}
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Indeed [mlr doesn't list](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/integrated_learners.html) lightgbm as supported. It [is supported in mlr3](https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_learners_classif.lightgbm.html) under the `mlr3extralearners` package.

Comment: @BenReiniger I see, then the whole code will change since `mlr3extralearners` does not have the `makeLearner` function. Any chance you could help me with the code and how do I change it?

Comment: I'm not a heavy user of R; maybe start at https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/discussions/667?